# SQL error 164 on a group by query

Tags: sql-server

I found a few examples of this error, but I can't seem to figure out how they relate to the query where I'm getting this error.

> "Error: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that
>   is not an outer reference. SQLState:  S1000 ErrorCode: 164"

From what I can tell it happens when you try to group by a literal (I don't think that's the case) or when you try to group by without using a variable from the inner query. . .which also isn't the case here.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
select Template_ID, sum(processed) as processed
from cache_table (nolock)
where Template_ID IN (208, 207)
and period between '2015-11-1' AND '2015-11-27'
group by 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't understand positional arguments in `group by`.  So, repeat the column name:

```
select Template_ID, sum(processed) as processed
from cache_table (nolock)
where Template_ID IN (208, 207) and
      period between '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-27'
group by Template_ID;
```

The positional syntax is permitted for `order by`.  In general, though, it is better to use column names in the `order by` clause as well.

Note:  some databases (such as Postgres) do support positional arguments for `group by`.

Comment: Oh man. .  right. I'm from psql land, so that makes a lot of sense. Thank you sir!